# Type parameterized arithmetic?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, parameterized

Trying to think of a way to subtract 5 minutes from 2 hours.

It doesn't make sense to subtract 5 from 2, because we end up with -3 generic time units, which is useless. But if "hour" is a subtype of "minute", we could convert 2 hours to 120 minutes, and yield 115 minutes, or 1 hour and 55 minutes.

Similarly, if we want to add 5 apples to 5 oranges, we cannot evaluate this in terms of apples, but might expect to end up with 10 fruit.

It seems in the above examples, and generally when using a number as an adjective, the integers need to be parameterized by the type of object they describing. I think it would be very useful if instead of declaring

```
val hours = 2
val minutes = 5
```

you could do something like

```
val hours = 2[Hour]
val minutes = 5[Minute]
val result = hours - minutes
assert (result == 115[Minute])
```

Does anything like this exist, would it be useful, and is it something that could be implemented?

**EDIT**: to clarify, the time example above is just a random example I thought up. My question is more whether in general the idea of parameterized Numerics is a useful concept, just as you have parameterized Lists etc. (The answer might be "no", I don't know!)

Comment: It can be, and has been, done in a lot of languages. But no clue about Scala :)

Comment: The answers suggest that you use a construct like `3.minutes`, which might return an instance of some time keeping type. If you want to go in that direction, you might want to take a look at the "Scala Joda Time" library, which is a Scala wrapper around Joda Time for Java. But your example looks more like you want to have a typeclass for this, like: `trait TimeValue[TimeUnit]`, where `TimeUnit` is a _phantom type_. This looks extremely interesting to me, as it might also be applied for other unit measures. I wonder if it can be done.

Comment: This is usually called _units_ or _measures_. Look up again with the proper terms -- there are libraries for that, and lots of prior discussion.

Comment: Here's one discussion:  [Implementing a Measured value in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331771/implementing-a-measured-value-in-scala)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this by having two classes for Hours and Minutes, along with an implicit conversion function from hours to minutes

```
trait TimeUnit
case class Hour(val num: Int) extends TimeUnit      
case class Minute(val num: Int) extends TimeUnit {
  def - (sub: Minute) = Minute(num - sub.num)
}

implicit def hour2Minute(hour: Hour) = Minute(hour.num * 60)
```

This allows you to do something like

```
val h = Hour(2) - Minute(30) //returns Minute(90)
```

Comment: The correct answer is "look up 'units of measure'", but accepting this because it's useful and by popular demand

Answer (score 3):

You can find some examples for this in the lift framework ([spec](https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/core/util/src/test/scala/net/liftweb/util/TimeHelpersSpec.scala)).

```
import net.liftweb.utils.TimeHelpers._
3.minutes == 6 * 30.seconds
```

(Note: it seems you need to have reasonable numbers for correct comparison. Eg. There may be no more than 60 seconds.)

Answer (score 2):

You might try [scala-time](https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time), which is a wrapper around [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/index.html) and makes it a bit more idiomatic for Scala, including some DSL to do time period computations, similar to what Brian Agnew suggested in his answer.

For instance,

```
2.hours + 45.minutes + 10.seconds
```

creates a Joda `Period`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a DSL would be of use here. So you could write

```
2.hours - 5.minutes
```

and the appropriate conversions would take place to convert 2 hours into a Hours object (value 2) etc.

Lots of resources exist describing Scala's DSL capabilities. e.g. [see this from O'Reilly](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html)

Comment: You will need to write `2.hours` or `(2 hours)` otherwise the compiler assumes `-` is an argument and not a method.