# Is it possible to implement F#'s infrastructure for Units of Measurement in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, f#, language-design, units-of-measurement

F# ships with special support for a unit of measurement system, which provides static type safety while compiling down to the numeric types instead of burdening the runtime with wrapping/unwrapping operations.

Is it possible to use some of Scala's type system magic to implement something comparable to that?

Comment: IMHO this not based on the type-system but on some kind of (pre)compiler support for those annotations (they won't find their way into the compiled assembly and only produce compiler errors) - so I don't think you could do really the same here without changing the scala-compiler too.

Comment: Perhaps as a hint: [ScalaU](http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/138/325)

Comment: As [this answer states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331771/implementing-a-measured-value-in-scala) there's already a Java implementation, so yes. I've also seen a few proofs-of-concept, but haven't studied any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of. You can encode the SI units quite easily using a type representation of integers in a tuple of exponents. See http://svn.assembla.com/svn/metascala/src/metascala/Units.scala for an example implementation.

It should also be possible to support an extensible units system if the units are encoded as a `TList` of pairs of a unit type and an integer (for example, `((M, _1), (S, _2))` where `M <: Unit` and `S <: Unit`). Calculating the types for quantity operations becomes a bit more complicated in this encoding.

Regarding performance there will always be a memory overhead for wrapping the value in a type containing the unit information. However there is probably no performance overhead in the actual operations as all unit checking is done at compile time.

Comment: I'm currently working with your library and trying to make it fully general in the number type, too. And so far it is hard, but I'm loving it. Thanks!

Comment: With value classes (http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) introduced in Scala 2.10 the runtime overhead doing units of measurement this way can be eliminated completely.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is *no*.

Now, someone is bound to point me to [Scalar](http://russp.us/scalar-scala.htm), but that gives *runtime* checking. Perhaps, then, point to the efforts of Jesper Nordenberg's [type-safe units](http://trac.assembla.com/metascala/browser/src/metascala/Units.scala) or Jim McBeath's [take on it](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/11/practical-church-numerals-in-scala.html), but these are cumbersome and awkward.

I'll point, instead to the [Units compiler plugin](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/compiler-plugins/units/trunk). It gave Scala, back in 2008/2009, a pretty good system of units, as can be seen in [this post](http://www.michaelnygard.com/blog/2009/05/units_of_measure_in_scala.html). It did so, however, by *extending* the compiler, which would not be necessary if the type system was enough. Alas, it has not been maintained and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the compiler plugin! What features does it have? Do you have an idea how long it would take to get the plugin compile again with Scala 2.10?

Comment: @soc See the article I linked. It is available from `sbaz`, but it didn't work even on latter versions of 2.7.x. I have no idea what work would it take to get it working, but if you are willing to have a go, I'd certainly be grateful. I miss it, just not enough to do the job myself.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about it, but I just stumbled accross this talk at Scala Days: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/ScalaDays+2011+Resources#ScalaDays2011Resources-ScalaUImplementingaScalalibraryforUnitsofMeasure

Comment: Adrian Fritch's [ScalaU library is on Github](https://github.com/adrianfr/scalau).

Comment: @Mike, Yes, it boxes. Not sure how well the JVM can eliminate this with escape analysis. There's not much to it beyond [this implementation file](https://github.com/adrianfr/scalau/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalau/units/Units_SI.scala).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Units of Measure - A Scala Macro System](http://www.furida.mu/blog/2013/04/12/units-of-measure-a-scala-macro-system/). It seems to satisfy your requirements.